# How to separate values of an key based on "." in .ini and insert in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, ini

I have an ini file with:

```
radio[type] = Radio
radio[label] = Radio Buttonnnnnnn
radio[id] = radio
radio[option] = casuta 1.casuta 2.casuta 3
```

And I use this:

```
foreach ($ini_array['FORM_SETTINGS'] as $type => $fieldsData) {

        if ($fieldsData['type'] == 'HTML'){
                $className = "PFBC\\Element\\{$fieldsData['type']}";
                $form->addElement(new $className($fieldsData['string']
                ));
            continue;}

        if ($fieldsData['type'] == 'Radio'){
                                    $key = $fieldsData['option'];

                $className = "PFBC\\Element\\{$fieldsData['type']}";
                $form->addElement(new $className($fieldsData['label'], $fieldsData['id'], array("casuta 1", "casuta 2", "casuta 3")
                ));
            continue;}
```

How to dynamical generate the array inside  based on the values taken from the `radio[option] = casuta 1.casuta 2.casuta 3` in .ini file

and this is the array stored in `$fieldsData`:

```
array (size=4)
  'type' => string 'Radio' (length=5)
  'label' => string 'Radio Buttonnnnnnn' (length=18)
  'id' => string 'radio' (length=5)
  'option' => string 'casuta 1.casuta 2.casuta 3' (length=26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `explode(".", $string)`. That will split a string into an array where delimiter used is `.`

Comment: THX THX this was the idea I need . 
`$key = explode('.', $fieldsData['option']);` then use the variable where I need, I was in deadlock. So simple ...